# access "implicit" metavar value in argument help string

Tags: python, argparse

When you call `add_argument` on an `argparse.ArgumentParser()` without an explicit action, you get the `"store"` action. In the auto-generated `--help` output you get the uppercase of the long option, unless you set `metavar`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--version', metavar='X.Y.Z')
parser.add_argument('--date'),
parser.parse_args(['--help'])
```

displays:

```
usage: try.py [-h] [--version X.Y.Z] [--date DATE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --version X.Y.Z
  --date DATE
```

In this I would call `X.Y.Z` an explicit metavar, and `DATE` an implicit metavar.

If you want to have more useful help you can do:

```
parser.add_argument('--version', metavar='X.Y.Z', 
                    help = "set version to % (metavar)s")
```

which gives (only changed lines shown):

```
  --version X.Y.Z  set version to X.Y.Z
```

and being able to use that `%(metavar)s` in the help string is nice because when you change `metavar='MAJOR.MINOR'`, the help doesn't need to be updated (which you are bound to forget).

But if you add the help for the `--date` argument, with the implicit metavar:

```
parser.add_argument('--date', 
                    help="use %(metavar)s instead of today's date")
```

you get:

```
  --date DATE      use None instead of today
```

And that `None` is not what I expected, nor what I want.

Of course I can always hard-code 'DATE' in the help, or explicitly provide the metavar (especially when it is used in the help string). But when I do that, I am bound to forget to update the metavar when I change the name of the long option.

Is there an "automatic" way to get `DATE` in the help string instead of `None` ?
Or am I using `%(metavar)s` where I should be using something else (and if so, what)?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do before calling `parser.parse_args()` is update those actions added to the `parser` that have a `metavar` attribute that is `None`:

```
for action in parser._actions:
    if not hasattr(action, 'metavar') or not hasattr(action, 'dest'):
        continue
    metavar = getattr(action, 'metavar')
    if metavar is None:
        action.metavar = action.dest.upper()
```

That generates output like:

```
  --version X.Y.Z  set version to X.Y.Z
  --date DATE      use DATE instead of today
```

But as we say in the BDFL's native language: "mooi is anders" ¹

---

¹ <sub>beautiful looks different</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be easy, at least not within `argparse`.

When you `add_argument` it creates an `Action` class object, and assigns attributes:

```
 a1 = parser.add_argument('--version', metavar='X.Y.Z')
 a2 = parser.add_argument('--date')
```

`a1.metavar` will be `'X.Y.Z'`, `a2.metavar` will be the default `None`.

That's the value that is used in the help line, something like:

```
`'help %(metavar)`%{'metavar':action.metavar}'
```

That `action.metavar` attribute can be modified after creating the Action, as demonstrated in the other answer.

But for the `usage` and first part of `help` it does something like:

```
def _metavar_formatter(self, action, default_metavar):
        if action.metavar is not None:
            result = action.metavar
        elif action.choices is not None:
            choice_strs = [str(choice) for choice in action.choices]
            result = '{%s}' % ','.join(choice_strs)
        else:
            result = default_metavar
        ...
```

`default_metavar` is different for `positionals` and `optionals`, but basically is derived from `action.dest`.  So the displayed `metavar` is generated on the fly, and not stored anywhere.

---

The `%(metavar)s` is handled in:

```
def _expand_help(self, action):
    params = dict(vars(action), prog=self._prog)
    for name in list(params):
        if params[name] is SUPPRESS:
            del params[name]
    for name in list(params):
        if hasattr(params[name], '__name__'):
            params[name] = params[name].__name__
    if params.get('choices') is not None:
        choices_str = ', '.join([str(c) for c in params['choices']])
        params['choices'] = choices_str
    return self._get_help_string(action) % params
```

`vars(action)` makes a dictionary from all the attributes of the `action`.

I can imagine creating a Formatter subclass that modifies one or more of the methods.  The existing subclasses work by modifying just one or two low level methods.  But to do that requires studying the code.

---

```
In [329]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [330]: a1 = p.add_argument('--version', metavar='X.Y.Z')
In [331]: a1
Out[331]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['--version'], dest='version', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar='X.Y.Z')
In [332]: vars(a1)
Out[332]: 
{'option_strings': ['--version'],
 'dest': 'version',
 'nargs': None,
 'const': None,
 'default': None,
 'type': None,
 'choices': None,
 'required': False,
 'help': None,
 'metavar': 'X.Y.Z',
 'container': <argparse._ArgumentGroup at 0x7f72ecc4b4a8>}
```

A help with several parameters:

```
In [333]: a1.help='help %(metavar)s, %(dest)s, %(required)s'
In [334]: p.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--version X.Y.Z]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --version X.Y.Z  help X.Y.Z, version, False
```